# How so I beat the Minotaur boss?

Tags: god-of-war

I’m at the Minotaur at Hades and I’m stuck. I get him down easily but can’t get past the QTE. I get the first two rotations to work all the time but the third ALWAYS fails. I just don’t get it. If it was inconsistent I would know it’s me but out of 40 or so tries, it’s always the third rotation that fails, 100%. Is the window for that rotation much smaller? I’m certain I do the third rotation just like the first two but it won’t work.

Has anybody hade issues here with the QTE? I’m really stumped and can’t really see how I can improve. I’ve even tried to be a bit sloppy and the first two rotations still work but not the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I’m certain I do the third rotation just like the first two but it won’t work.

The third rotation isn't "exactly" like the first two.

According to [this video](https://youtu.be/2fso3va_OAo?t=63), the rotations would be:

1. clockwise down
2. clockwise down
3. clockwise **up**

Note that the player messes up and has to try again, the second time it's:

1. clockwise **up**
2. clockwise **up**
3. **counterclockwise** down

Which means that the rotations aren't always the same!

Basically, you need to pay attention to:

- clockwise/counterclockwise
- up/down/full circle (final rotation)

Note that you'll need to be twice as fast for the full rotation, because the input window is the same as for the half-rotations, but now you need to move twice as far.